# How to find value in Pirority_queue which contains pair<int,int>?

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue

Normally we can find whether a value present in priority queue using heap.find(value). If it not present, it will return end().

Now I have a priority queue, which defined like this

```
priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>, fun> min_heap;
```

I want to find whether a pair exist in this based on of the value in pair. How to find it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::priority_queue` does not give any access to elements other than the top one, nor does it allow outside access to the underlying container. So if you need an iterable priority queue, you have to code something yourself. You could create something like this:

```
template <class T, class Container = std::vector<T>, class Compare = std::less<typename Container::value_type>>
class IterableQueue : public std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare>
{
public:
  using std::priority_queue<T, Container, Compare>::priority_queue;

  const Container& container() const { return this->c; }
};
```

Note that in general, it's a bad idea to publicly inherit from standard library containers (like my example above does), because they don't have virtual destructors and thus allowing a conversion to the base container is potentially dangerous.

In production code, it would be better to employ private inheritance and publish (via `using` declarations) the members you want accessible (essentially just all of them).

Also be aware that giving the outside world non-`const` access to the underlying container would be a pretty bad idea, since it could violate the priority queue's invariants and lead to Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a tmp Priority Queue of the same type passing your original PQ to the constructor to copy the elements, then of course you can check the top and pop until you find your wanted pair or the new PQ is empty:

```
pair<int, int> wantedPair = {5, 3};
bool found = false;
priority_queue<pair<int,int>, vector<pair<int,int>>, fun> tmp(min_heap);
while(tmp.empty() == false) {
    if (wantedPair == tmp.top()) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }

    tmp.pop();
}
```

You can make a template function for find if you want to use it more than once with different kinds of PQs.